# (Python) Getting an error inputting and outputting a file

Tags: python, file

I am relatively new to Python and working with inputting and outputting in files. Here is the input file:

```
    1 3
    1 1
    1 0
    20 30
```

and here is my code that takes this as "soccer_in.txt" and is suppose to output the following into "soccer_out.txt":

```
    Season: 1, Games Played: 1, Points earned: 3
    Possible Win-Tie-Loss Records
    -----------------------------
    1-0-0

    Season: 2, Games Played: 1, Points earned: 1
    Possible Win-Tie-Loss Records
    -----------------------------
    0-1-0

    Season: 3, Games Played: 1, Points earned: 0
    Possible Win-Tie-Loss Records
    -----------------------------
    0-0-1

    Season: 4, Games Played: 20, Points earned: 30
    Possible Win-Tie-Loss Records
    -----------------------------
    10-0-10
    9-3-8
    8-6-6
    7-9-4
    6-12-2
    5-15-0
```

using this code:

```
def process_season(output_file, season, games_played, points_earned):
    output_file.write("Season: " + str(season) + ", Games Played: " + str(games_played) +
          ", Points earned: " + str(points_earned))
    output_file.write("Possible Win-Tie-Loss Records")
    output_file.write("-----------------------------")
    wins = points_earned // 3
    ties = points_earned % 3
    losses = games_played - wins - ties
    while (wins >= 0) and (losses >= 0):
            output_file.write(str(wins) + "-" + str(ties) + "-" + str(losses))
            wins -= 1
            ties += 3
            losses -= 2
    output_file.write()

# --------------------------------------

def process_seasons(input_file, output_file):
    season_number = 0
    for season in input_file:
        season_number += 1
    process_season(output_file, season_number, season[0], season[1])

# --------------------------------------
f_in=open("soccer-in.txt", "r")
f_out=open("soccer-out.txt", "w+")
process_seasons(f_in, f_out)
```

But I'm getting an error that says
File "C:\Users", line 12, in process_season
    wins = points_earned // 3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'

Any help would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: When you read something from a file, that will have a type `str`. Just put `int(points_earned) // 3` there and you should be fine as long as `points_earned` is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to divide a string.

In `process_season()` you can try casting `season[0]` and `season[1]` as integers.

```
process_season(output_file, season_number, int(season[0]), int(season[1]))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!